# Post English Civil War history books/novels

Tags: english-civil-war

I'm looking for some post English Civil War history textbooks or novels aimed at the young-teenage (13) are range. My aim is to help my son improve his critical writing history homework. Are there any that people would suggest?

Thanks

Angus

Comment: Book recommendations are usually considered off-topic for History.SE, as the answers tend to be opinion-based and often there is no "correct" answer.

Comment: Only good novels I know of set in that era are Neal Stevenson's Baroque Cycle, which starts just after the Great Fire, and includes the Glorious Revolution. However, they are kind of aimed at adults, and the books themselves are of a rather intimidating girth.

Comment: Harry potter takes place after the English Civil War